# Setup a https client in Java

Tags: java, https

I'm very new to HTTPS/SSL so excuse my lack of knowledge. Right now I'm trying to setup a simple Java client in which it connects to a web server through HTTPS. I've seen some example code online but can't seem to really make sense of it. Also I was wondering if there is a difference between setting it up on a Windows machine compared to another type of OS.

If anybody knows a good tutorial on this or can head me towards the right direction it would be appreciated.

Comment: What Java libraries are you using for your connections?

Comment: either tell us what exactly you don't understand, or what piece of code doesn't work.

Comment: I don't have any code to show that I've written because I don't even know what libraries to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/sslguide.html) is open source code that does what you need. It makes little difference what OS you use.

Answer (score -1):

See also the JSSE Reference Guide in the Javadoc.